# MS SQL Server instance name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Quick question guys!

Will there be any issues if I use the default instance (MSSQLSERVER) for both test and production environments? They are on separate physical servers. I'm using MS SQL Server 2012 which will run on clustered Windows Server 2012?

Thanks in advance and Happy New Year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will be no problem to have multiple default instances in your environment. The only real restriction here is you can only have **one default instance per machine**.

You will have different network names for the different failover cluster instances. In short, if I'm understanding your question correctly then no that'll be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine.  As long as they are on different servers ("Prod" and "Dev"), you would just address them across the network by their server name.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Kath! I am tempted to just easily use a different name but I'd like the idea of using the default instance as it does not require clients to specify the name of the instance to make a connection (as per MS$).

Answer (score 1):

A a **Default** instance can be created one per server and in my experience it is confusing to install a default instance on a cluster.

I generally prefer to be named instance - just for better manageability.

for eg. for a multi instance failover cluster, I would normally go with naming convention as below :

Note: You can adjust the naming conventions as per your need.

> **Physical Machine Names :**
>
> ```
>  Node 1: SQLPROD1
>
>  Node 2: SQLPROD2
> ```
>
> **Windows Cluster Name:** SQLPROD
>
> **Named instance Name :**
>
> ```
>  SQLPROD\NY01
>  SQLPROD\NY02
> ```